# Adding the "Like Button" to my Facebook Page

Tags: plugins, facebook-like, facebook-social-plugins, facebook-page

I've found the code but not where to put it on my Facebook page.. not my website.  Everyone keeps referencing dropping it in a code block, but I haven't been able to find an example of how to do this.

Comment: What code did you find?  What were the directions?  Do you have a link to its source?

Comment: Where on your Facebook Page are you trying to put this Like Button? Are you aware that all Facebook Pages already come with Like Buttons next to their page name at the top of every Fan Page's page (such as Wall, Info, etc.)? If you are already a fan of that page, the button will not appear for you.

The only place where you can put additional Like Buttons on your Facebook Fan Page are within page tabs as Igy mentions below. The link they've provided will give you a simple tab for YOUR fan page, which allows you to put any html you want (including the code for the like button).

Answer (score 4):

There's already a Like button on Facebook Pages if the user viewing the page doesn't already like the page. If you want to add a like button on your Page for another entity (such as a website, article, or a different Page) you'll need to install a tab to your page where you can put HTML content.

There are several third party applications that allow you to do this, one of the popular ones is http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=190322544333196 - you could add a new tab to your page with some static content (images, etc) and include the Like button on that tab.

There is no way to embed a like button for an external entity into a post on the page's wall, which i suspect is what you're currently trying to do.

Comment: The like button is already on there.  I think they are trying to get me to add one that lets me track followers and my page shows up on THEIR page.  I have the code.  I just don't know where to put it.  I don't want to add a like button for another entity.. lol  That's why I kept putting my FACEBOOK page in bold.  That's all I kept finding is what you sent me.. ;-)